# 12.04=>14.04 or 16.04 Broken Upgrade (not sure which upgrade rev.)

Tags: 12.04

Was running 12.04 dual OS with Windows7, notified Ubuntu upgrade available. Tried to load, something glitched, now cannot open 12.04 or upgrade. Still get grub loader screen but when try to open Ubuntu or Ubuntu w/ options just get few screens of code lines then system hangs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to new version of OS from an existing OS is called a "dirty upgrade," and in my experience this almost never works 100%. Most likely is your graphics driver isn't loading properly. There's 2 things you can do:

- if you want to fiddle with it, from `GRUB` select `Advanced Options` and then `recovery`. From the menu that opens, you can select `network` and then `root shell`, this will allow you to run upgrade commands (`sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`), will allow you to poke at your system (`lshw -C display`, etc) and will allow you to install new drivers and such.
- if you just want to get your system fixed and working again, backup your data (using the root shell from above), download and burn a 14.04 or 16.04 (your choice) iso, burn it to a DVD or USB key, then wipe your drive or partition and do a clean install.